Replit code not showing output after sometimes without showing anything. It comes to this stage after asking for signature
This is the code, Its related to auto forwarder for telegram messages using source chat id and destination chat id.

import asyncio
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import ChatIdInvalidError


class TelegramForwarder:
    def __init__(self, api_id, api_hash, phone_number):
        self.api_id = api_id
        self.api_hash = api_hash
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.client = TelegramClient('session_' + phone_number, api_id, api_hash)

    async def forward_messages_to_channel_pairs(self, chat_pairs, keywords, signature):
        await self.client.connect()

        if not await self.client.is_user_authorized():
            await self.client.send_code_request(self.phone_number)
            await self.client.sign_in(self.phone_number, input('Enter the code: '))

        # Adjusted to handle three values: source_id, destination_id, and topic_id
        last_message_ids = {source_id: (await self.client.get_messages(source_id, limit=1))[0].id for source_id, _, _ in chat_pairs}

        while True:
            print("Checking for messages and forwarding them...")
            for source_chat_id, destination_chat_id, topic_id in chat_pairs:
                # Get new messages since the last checked message for the current source chat
                messages = await self.client.get_messages(source_chat_id, min_id=last_message_ids[source_chat_id], limit=None)

                for message in reversed(messages):
                    if keywords:
                        if message.text and any(keyword in message.text.lower() for keyword in keywords):
                            print(f"Message contains a keyword: {message.text}")
                            await self.forward_message(destination_chat_id, message.text, signature, topic_id)
                    else:
                        await self.forward_message(destination_chat_id, message.text, signature, topic_id)

                    last_message_ids[source_chat_id] = max(last_message_ids[source_chat_id], message.id)

            await asyncio.sleep(5)

    async def forward_message(self, destination_chat_id, message_text, signature, topic_id=None):
        try:
            entity = await self.client.get_input_entity(destination_chat_id)

            # Convert topic ID if it's out of valid range
            if topic_id is not None:
                topic_id = self.convert_to_signed_integer(topic_id)
                # Only proceed if topic_id is valid
                if self.is_valid_signed_integer(topic_id):
                    await self.client.send_message(entity, message_text + f"\n\n{signature}", reply_to=topic_id)
                    print(f"Message forwarded to topic {topic_id} in chat {destination_chat_id}")
                else:
                    print(f"Invalid topic ID: {topic_id}, skipping.")
            else:
                await self.client.send_message(entity, message_text + f"\n\n{signature}")
                print(f"Message forwarded to chat {destination_chat_id}")

        except ChatIdInvalidError:
            print(f"Invalid chat ID: {destination_chat_id}.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to forward to {destination_chat_id}: {e}")

    def convert_to_signed_integer(self, number):
        """Convert an unsigned integer to a signed integer."""
        if number > 2147483647:
            return number - 4294967296
        return number

    def is_valid_signed_integer(self, number):
        """Check if the number is within the valid range of a signed 32-bit integer."""
        return -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647


# Function to read credentials from file
def read_credentials():
    try:
        with open("credentials.txt", "r") as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            api_id = int(lines[0].strip())
            api_hash = lines[1].strip()
            phone_number = lines[2].strip()
            return api_id, api_hash, phone_number
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Credentials file not found.")
        return None, None, None

# Function to write credentials to file
def write_credentials(api_id, api_hash, phone_number):
    with open("credentials.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(str(api_id) + "\n")
        file.write(api_hash + "\n")
        file.write(phone_number + "\n")

async def main():
    api_id, api_hash, phone_number = read_credentials()

    if api_id is None or api_hash is None or phone_number is None:
        api_id = input("Enter your API ID: ")
        api_hash = input("Enter your API Hash: ")
        phone_number = input("Enter your phone number: ")
        write_credentials(api_id, api_hash, phone_number)

    forwarder = TelegramForwarder(api_id, api_hash, phone_number)

    print("Choose an option:")
    print("1. List Chats")
    print("2. Forward Messages")

    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")

    if choice == "1":
        await forwarder.list_chats()
    elif choice == "2":
        print("Enter pairs of source and destination chat IDs (e.g., 'source_id1:destination_id1:topic_id1, source_id2:destination_id2:topic_id2'):")
        chat_pairs_input = input("Enter the chat ID pairs (comma separated): ")

        # Adjusted to handle three values: source_id, destination_id, and topic_id
        chat_pairs = [tuple(map(int, pair.split(':'))) for pair in chat_pairs_input.split(",")]

        print("Enter keywords if you want to forward messages with specific keywords, or leave blank to forward every message!")
        keywords = input("Put keywords (comma separated if multiple, or leave blank): ").split(",")

        signature = input("Enter your signature: ")

        await forwarder.forward_messages_to_channel_pairs(chat_pairs, keywords, signature)
    else:
        print("Invalid choice")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


The runs om normal IDE's but when its on replit it just shows running after asking for signature without showing anything further. Some searched for some answers but I only got responses related to network limitation by replit. If you could help it would be really appreciated. I need it to run on cloud if you could suggest other alternatives to please do.

You could try something like Google Cloud/App Scripts (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33175974) or PythonAnywhere
